# JPlayer on Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 to create my site. I am trying to install Jplayer into my site, however i am fairly new to this. I built the javascript with Dashcode and it put it into my rails folder, but i do not know if i need to move it into the apps folder or just leave it in the folder as my project. I am also supposed to be putting code into my  (html) but Rails usually doesn't do it that way, so can i just put the code anywhere in the page? I have been following the "Quick start" tutorial for jPlayer by Happyworm but i am getting this

[image]

which is not what it is supposed to look like.
This is a [link](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/quick-start-guide/step-6-audio/) the the second to last step in the tutorial where i am supposed to get a visual image of the audio player which also includes the code i have in my page. I know i put a lot of questions in but any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not loading a stylesheets/theme for jplayer.

Comment: do you know how to do that? I mean i have the Jplayer.swf in a folder called js which is in the folder for the webpage, but i do not know how to load it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to load a theme (You can find the standard one [here](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/jPlayer.Blue.Monday.2.1.0.zip))

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/jPlayer/jplayer.blue.monday.css" />
  <!-- ... -->
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

write this inside you head tag:

```
<link href="http://jplayer.org/latest/skin/pink.flag/jplayer.pink.flag.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```